# How to use Dagger's AndroidInjection within Android library without access to the Application class

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

During the development of a **library** or let's say **plugin** for a project I faced an issue with Dagger. In the past we used the old Dagger API which is basically done by accessing the component through a static reference and injecting the Activity or custom view by it's own.

When we tried to migrate the project to the new Dagger API and therefore the usage of:

```
AndroidInjection.inject(this) // Just inject the Activity without knowledge of the dependency graph
```

we faced some runtime issues when we try to start an Activity of the library.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class<eu.applabs.dagger2library.feature.FeatureActivity>
    at dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector.inject(DispatchingAndroidInjector.java:104)
    at dagger.android.AndroidInjection.inject(AndroidInjection.java:59)
    at eu.applabs.dagger2library.feature.FeatureActivity.onCreate(FeatureActivity.kt:22)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

The issue could be fixed when every module of the library is added to the component of the application but there need to be a better way by using the regular component or subcomponent structure.

Therefore I decided to create a sample project on [GitHub](https://github.com/mklschreiber/dagger2librarysample)

I would really appreciate if I could get some support because all provided samples don't cover the usecase of a library...

Comment: _when every module of the library is added to the component of the application_ you can have one module in your library that includes the others

Answer (score -2):

You can use dagger's support classes. Take a look at this https://medium.com/@ibrahimsn98/android-mvvm-with-dagger-2-retrofit-rxjava-architecture-components-6f5da1a75135

Comment: The main problem is that @mkl is creating an Android Library, it may not have an direct access to an application itself. In my case I cannot enforce my library users to use DaggerApplication or HasAndroidInjector in  Application itself (as article suggest). In other words it does not solve this problem